# Is this group index infinite?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, infinite-groups

Let $G=\left(\begin{matrix}a&b\\c&d\end{matrix}\right)$ where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$ and determinant = 1, be a group.

And let $H=\left(\begin{matrix}1&n\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)$ where ($n\in\mathbb{Z}$) be a subgroup of $G$.

What is the index $[G:H]$?

---

$H$ is clearly infinite so $G$ must be infinite so the index must be infinite. Does this make sense?

Comment: That does not make sense, clearly $\mathbb{Z}$ and $n \mathbb{Z}$ are infinite but $[\mathbb{Z} : n \mathbb{Z}]=n$

Comment: @PaulPlummer OK, that makes sense. Now I do not know how do I find the index or determine that it is infinite?

Comment: I am sure there are a couple ways. But just start with the definition of index and calculate $\left(\begin{matrix}a&b\\c&d\end{matrix}\right) H$ (so calc $\left(\begin{matrix}a&b\\c&d\end{matrix} \right) \left(\begin{matrix}1&n\\0&1\end{matrix}\right )$ ).

Comment: @PaulPlummer I don't really see the light still : $\left(\begin{matrix}a&an+b\\c&cn+d\end{matrix}\right)$. It has the same determinant (ad-bc)

Comment: Yes but the first column is fixed, so each coset has a fixed column. Are there infinitely many possible choices for the first column?

Comment: @PaulPlummer So for each element in $G$ there is infinite such cosets so the index is infinite. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not exactly. For each element $g$ there is a coset $gH$. You need to show there are infinitely many distinct cosets, I outlined the idea, that you look at the coset $gH$, and notice all the matrices have the same first column in that one coset. Given that cosets partition $G$, can there only be finitely many "first" columns, or are there infinitely many first columns in $G$? (you have a set of matrices that have infinitely many different second columns ($H$), can you use the same idea to get infinitely many first columns instead)

Comment: The fact that $G$ and $H$ are infinite groups does not imply that $ [G:H]$  is infinite.  For example when $J$ is an infinite group and $K$ is a finite group with identity $i_K$, let $ G=J\times K$ and $H=J\times \{i_K\}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $$\left(\begin{matrix}a&b\\c&d\end{matrix} \right) \left(\begin{matrix}1&n\\0&1\end{matrix}\right )= \left(\begin{matrix}a&an+b\\c&cn+d\end{matrix}\right).$$ Given that calculation we can see all the elements in the coset $gH$ have the same first column as $g$.

So to show that $H$ is infinite index we only have to show there are infinitely many possible first columns. Well $$l_n= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ n & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ give infinitely many different first columns and $l_n \in G$, so each $l_n H$ is a distinct coset. There are infinitely many, so $H$ has infinite index.

Answer (score 0):

Each $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ yields a distinct coset

$$\begin{pmatrix}k & k-1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}H = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}k & nk + k - 1 \\ 1 & n+1\end{pmatrix} : n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\},$$

so $[G:H]$ is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the "opposite" subgroup $K = \{ \left( \begin{array}{clcr} 1 & 0\\m & 1 \end{array} \right) : m \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. If $a,b \in K$ are different, then $a^{-1}b$ must lie outside $H$, since $H \cap K = \{I \}$ and we certainly have $a^{-1}b \in K$. Thus $\{ aH : a \in K \}$ is an infinite set of distinct cosets of $H$ in $G$ ( note that $K$ is infinite, just as $H$ is).